# do I need to make gradle project as Android Library to debug it

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android Studio gradle project, with project files in `src` folder and also CordovaLib library files.
[image: project structure]

`CordovaLib` gradle project specified as a dependency in main `build.gradle` file in this way:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    for (subproject in getProjectList()) {
        compile project(subproject)
    }
}
```

However, `CordovaLib` is not recognized by Android Studio as Android Library Module and most likely isn't added to classpath:

[image]

Whenever I debug my application on Android, I can't debug files placed inside `CordovaLib/src` folder. Is it possible that it's because CordovaLib is not recognized by Android Studio as module? Do I need to somehow turn it into the module?

PS. The project wasn't created by me, it was imported as an output of `cordova prepare` command.